# PDO: Calculate a value using data from two different tables

Tags: php, pdo

What I'm trying to do is calculate the total value of land that a company owns for an online game. The current value of the land for each city is stored in the city_list table as acre_price. The amount of acres that a company owns is stored in the company_land table as amount. So the total value would be acre_price * amount, and do that for every city that the company owns land in, and then add it all up.

The reason why acre_price can't be stored in the company_land table is because it is a constantly changing value - it can change every few minutes if there is enough activity, and keeping the land value up to date in two different tables would be a lot of work.

This is what I have come up with, and it halfway works. It calculates the correct value, but only for 1 city that a company owns land in (the most recent entry in the database). I need it to calculate the value for ALL entries in the database. I've tried changing fetch to fetchAll in the 2nd query, but that broke the code and only displayed a white page.

Does anyone know what I would need to do to achieve this?

Thanks in advance :)

```
$sth = null; $count = 0; $data = array();
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM company_land WHERE company_id = ?");
$company_land_query = $sth->execute(array($_GET['id']));

if($company_land_query){
while($row = $sth->fetch()){
    $land_data = $row;
    ++$count;
}
    if($count > 0){
        $sth = null; $count = 0; $data = array();
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM city_list WHERE city_id = ?");
        $land_price_query = $sth->execute(array($land_data['city_id']));
            while($row = $sth->fetch()){
            $city_data = $row;
            $land_value = $land_data['amount'] * $city_data['acre_price'];
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to figure out what went wrong.  Turn on error reporting, and configure PDO to throw exceptions so you can see what happened.  Also, have you thought about doing the math in your query?  Normally, you would leave this sort of thing up to the application, but if you want to do something with that data at the data level, it might be better to do it in the query, if it is simple enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing the first while loop too soon, it should enclose the second loop because all the first loop is doing is counting the number of rows returned from the first query and only returns the last row from that query ($land_data is being overwritten several times without being used).

The code should work better like this, note that I've moved some code around and removed several lines that aren't needed:

```
/*
 * Prepare both queries here, moved the city_list query out from the loops, no
 * need to prepare it multiple times.
 */
$sthLand = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM company_land WHERE company_id = ?");
$sthCity = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM city_list WHERE city_id = ?");
$land_value = 0;

if ($sthLand->execute(array($_GET['id']))) {
    while($land_data = $sthLand->fetch()) {
        if ($sthCity->execute(array($land_data['city_id']))) {
            while($city_data = $sthCity->fetch()) {
                $land_value += $land_data['amount'] * $city_data['acre_price'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

$land_value contains the total land value owned by the company.

Comment: Thank you! This does exactly what I was trying to do, but in a better format than I was trying to do it in.

Comment: Good to be of help, I actually upvoted peterm's answer myself as he's got an even better solution in my opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate that value using single `SELECT` statement with a query like this

```sql
SELECT SUM(l.amount * c.acre_price) total
  FROM company_land l INNER JOIN
       city_list c ON l.city_id = c.city_id
```

*It's not tested, since DDL for tables and sample data hasn't been provided.*

Comment: I hadn't thought of performing the math within the query itself - thank you for the answer, it appears there are several ways to do this.

Comment: You're quite welcome. Calculating it on db side saves you a bunch of code in php and what is more important in your case it saves you a number (equals to the number of cities) of roundtrips to the database with subsequent queries. And those operations are usually costly.